# When opening a conversation from a deep link to a file in channel in teams, is it supposed to create new conversations?

Tags: microsoft-teams, deep-linking

We have a deep link to a file in channel that is created according to the documentation provided here.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/concepts/build-and-test/deep-links#generate-deep-links-to-file-in-channel

[Show Conversation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NnKAe.png)
Is it normal behaviour that when clicking show conversation in the top right corner of the viewer that it creates a new conversation each time you click show conversation?(So first you click show conversation, it creates a new one, you then hide it and click show conversation again and it creates a new one again).

[First time opening and typing something](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eYHZH.png)

[Close the conversation and open it again](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6Tw8f.png)

[What it looks like in the channel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P8MHH.png)

Is there any way to make sure that the show conversation opens up the correct conversation that has already been created?

**Edit:**
Steps to reproduce.

1. Get a drive item for example using graph explorer graph{dot}microsoft{dot}com/v1.0/drives//items/
2. Get team id graph{dot}microsoft{dot}com/v1.0/me/joinedTeams
3. Get channel id graph{dot}microsoft{dot}com/v1.0/teams//channels
4. Find your tenantId graph{dot}microsoft{dot}com/v1.0/organization
5. Create deep link using teams{dot}microsoft{dot}com/l/file/?tenantId=&fileType=&objectURL=&baseUrl=&serviceName=&threadId=&groupId= where fileId is the guid part of the eTag of the driveItem, fileType is the type, the objectUrl is the sharepoint webUrl from the driveItem, baseUrl is the baseUrl of the file, threadId is the channelId & groupId is the teamId
6. Follow the link created(or put it in a message extensions card for example) and then in the viewer in teams open the show conversation button. It will generate a new conversation thread each time the button is clicked or closed

Sorry for the graph links not being links, since I don't have enough reputation on SO I was not allowed to post all the links

Comment: Can you please add screenshots of the behavior you see?

Comment: Added some screnshots to the original post

Comment: @Ingibergur-we are not getting the proper context. Could you please share repro steps or any sample which you refer.so we can try it from our end?

Comment: Please also share how this is related to programming

Comment: @Sayali-MSFT Added some steps for how to reproduce this.

Comment: We are tried to repro the scenario. But unable to repro, Could you please provide video for which you are facing?

Comment: Here's a link to a video reproducing the issue 
https://unimaze-my.sharepoint.com/:v:/p/ingibergur/EVInbgyRv6JKqMkARZ0cma8BrPUj8ffmt0YeFWjigGi8Zw?e=Kdarwo

Comment: We are checking it from our end and let you know once we get any way to do it?

Comment: @Sayali-MSFT It seems like the issue has been solved. One day it just started working. I assume some bug fix was done on your end